# Efficient matrix multiplication

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning

I have a list of vectors `vecs = {vec1, vec2, ..., vecN}` where `veci` is a list with length $N$.

Now I have a matrix $N\times N$ called `mat`.

I would like to efficiently get all the numbers `veci.mat.veci` for $i=1$ to $N$ in a list. How do I do it?

Comment: Perhaps, `MapThread[Dot,{vecs.mat,vecs}]`? (untested).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Is your [matrix multiplication engine](http://radhakrishna.typepad.com/rks_musings/2010/01/trivia.html) broken?

Comment: @belisarius Let's say it is just busy :). Actually, even just a simplest sample input with expected output would make this question way more attractive, and I guess not just for me.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin It works. Thanks!

Comment: All right, I will then post this as an answer, to not keep this among the unanswered questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way:

```
MapThread[Dot,{vecs.mat,vecs}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way:

```
Total[vecs.mat * vecs, {2}]
```

If the vectors happen to come naturally as the columns of `vecs`,
rather than its rows, then this will get what you want:

```
Total[vecs * mat.vecs]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to calculate is to leave everything in matrix form

```
v = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {m=5, 10}];
mat = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 10}]; 
Diagonal[v.mat.Transpose[v]]
```

Since we're looking for fast ways, this seems faster:

```
v = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {m=1000, 10}];
mat = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 10}];
v[[#]].mat.v[[#]] & /@ Range[m]
```